# Maximize site usability in different browsers

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser

My site loads on most recent versions of IE fine, but on others and chrome/firefox not so well.  Is there some cheatsheet that list issues of portability I can use to fix those quickly?  I am only using jQuery and some ASP.

**Edit: OP's comment:**

I am using jquery to build a table on the fly, which contains results returned from an ajax request. I can see the results were generated, but the users claim they can't see them.

Comment: What do you mean with *visability*?

Comment: I am using jquery to build a table on the fly, which contains results returned from an ajax request.

I can see the results were generated, but the users claim they can't see them.

Comment: Oh, that way. You'll really need to provide an SSCCE then: http://sscce.org

Comment: OK, here is the code sample demonstrating the ajax request and results proccessing http://pastebin.com/m5fed41e1.

Sorry it isn't that tidy.

Comment: BTW the localhost usage in the code is intentional for the snippet

Answer (score 3):

There's not really such a cheatsheet available. In general, just using a [(X)HTML strict doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) and a webpage which [validates](http://validator.w3.org/) and a (separate) CSS sheet which [validates](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/), should work on any webbrowser the world wide web is aware of. Once done that, the remnant of the misbehaviours/bugs are often at CSS level and MSIE-only. For that you need to learn about the [common MSIE CSS bugs](http://haslayout.net/css/) and fix it accordingly.

At JavaScript level you don't need to worry that much as jQuery itself is already designed to be crossbrowser compatible. As ASP is a server side view technology which just generates/sends plain HTML to the response, it has not much to do here. It's all about the HTML/CSS which you have in your own control.

**Edit**: made community wiki as this doesn't answer the OP's actual question and I don't want to delete the answer because others may find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to ensure cross-browser compatibility, but sites such as http://browsershots.org/ will help determine which browsers are displaying data incorrectly

If you are using jquery then invalid javascript could be a possible reason for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your comments seem to indicate that your users are seeing problems that you're not able to replicate, possibly because you don't have the specific browser versions they're using.  You need to see what your users are seeing.  Try one of the sites that display your site as viewed by different browsers.  http://browsershots.org/ is one.

Comment: True I cant replicate the errors and http://browsershots.org isn't helpfull because the sites requires interactivity in order to get the results table

Comment: Force the request (call the function) so you can see it on browsershots.

Comment: This is an unrelated comment but you deleted your answer so I couldn't alert you. Take another look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167283/advice-on-logic-circuits-and-serial-communications

Answer (score 0):

> *I am using jquery to build a table on the fly, which contains results returned from an ajax request. I can see the results were generated, but the users claim they can't see them.*

Maybe the request URL was wrong. Try with an absolute URL or a domain-relative URL (i.e. starting with `/`. Nevertheless, it's still shooting in the dark without an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). At least I suspect that it's just a coding mistake and that MSIE was (again) been *too* forgiving in that.

**Update**: I checked your JS code at pastebin and it turns out that you aren't using jQuery at all, but just "plain vanilla" JavaScript, with under each the MSIE-proprietary `innerHTML`. If you *actually* make use of [jQuery](http://jquery.com) in your webapp, then I would port all the JS to jQuery so that it will be crossbrowser compatible.

Comment: interesting idea! going to check that

Comment: I checked the request URL its absolute and correct.

Also added a SSCCE link in an above comment.