# Advice on logic circuits and serial communications

Tags: c#, hardware, serial-port, circuit

As far as I understand the serial port so far, transferring data is done over pin 3. As shown here:
[image: Serial Port Pinout]

There are two things that make me uncomfortable about this. The first is that it seems to imply that the two connected devices agree on a signal speed and the second is that even if they are configured to run at the same speed you run into possible synchronization issues... right? Such things can be handled I suppose but it seems like there must be a simpler method.

What seems like a better approach to me would be to have one of the serial port pins send a pulse that indicates that the next bit is ready to be stored. So if we're hooking these pins up to a shift register we basically have: (some pulse pin)->clk, tx->d

Is this a common practice? Is there some reason not to do this?

*EDIT*

Mike shouldn't have deleted his answer. This [I<sup>2</sup>C (2 pin serial)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I2C#Timing_diagram) approach seems fairly close to what I did. The serial port doesn't have a clock you're right nobugz but that's basically what I've done. See here:

```
private void SendBytes(byte[] data)
{
    int baudRate = 0;
    int byteToSend = 0;
    int bitToSend = 0;
    byte bitmask = 0;

    byte[] trigger = new byte[1];
    trigger[0] = 0;

    SerialPort p;
    try
    {
        p = new SerialPort(cmbPorts.Text);
    }
    catch
    {
        return;
    }

    if (!int.TryParse(txtBaudRate.Text, out baudRate)) return;
    if (baudRate < 100) return;
    p.BaudRate = baudRate;

    for (int index = 0; index < data.Length * 8; index++)
    {
        byteToSend = (int)(index / 8);
        bitToSend = index - (byteToSend * 8);
        bitmask = (byte)System.Math.Pow(2, bitToSend);

        p.Open();
        p.Parity = Parity.Space;
        p.RtsEnable = (byte)(data[byteToSend] & bitmask) > 0;

        s = p.BaseStream;
        s.WriteByte(trigger[0]);

        p.Close();
    }
}
```

Before anyone tells me how ugly this is or how I'm destroying my transfer speeds my quick answer is I don't care about that. My point is this seems much much simpler than the method you described in your answer nobugz. And it wouldn't be as ugly if the .Net SerialPort class gave me more control over the pin signals. Are there other serial port APIs that do?

Comment: One reason not to do it would be incompatibilities, it's no longer a RS232  ... best to look at more recent serial x-fer interfaces (e.g. usb) where these issues seem to have been addressed.

Comment: why did you tag this  c-sharp?

Comment: Do you want something related to c#?

Comment: Untagging as C#.  I think that was a mistag.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't posted the code yet and I forgot to remove the tag in the mean time.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that on RS-232, data is transmitted on pin 3.  There are many types of serial protocols - for example, I2C, SPI, USB, and, especially in the embedded world, serial ports with a dedicated clock line and two data lines.  RS-232 is cheap, and easy to implement in hardware, but has lower maximum data rates than other serial options.  By the way, the chip at the heart of an RS-232 port is called a Universal Asynchronous Receiver/Transmitter.  The Asynchronous refers to each ports' clock being independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the approach is *similar* to the I2C approach described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C).

Answer (score 2):

It already works this way.  Each byte is transmitted with a non-data start bit first.  That lets the receiver synchronize its clock.  And there's at least one stop bit, that lets the receiver verify that the baudrate is not so much off that the last transmitted data bit is unreliable.  With 8 data bits, that yields 10 total bits, providing 10% tolerance on the baudrate.  Being off more generates a framing error.

Early PC designs readily took advantage of this.  The UART's clock was generated by a cheap crystal, present in any TV set to synch the chrominance carrier off the color burst, 3.579545 MHz.  The oscillator divides it by two, the UART divides the input clock by 16, yielding 3579545 / 32 = 111861 Hz.  The baudrate divisor then selects the frequency, the divisor for 9600 baud is 12.  111861 / 12 = 9322 baud, a 2.9% error.  Well within the 10% tolerance.  Also explains why 110,000 baud was the maximum.

Comment: That hardware is already available, every UART chip has it.  You seem determined to do it your way, good luck with that.

Comment: =\ I'm not determined to do it my way. I'm genuinely curious if there's good reason for not doing it my way.